# Creating view of multiple tables of same column names from multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, join, view

I currently have **two tables named t1 and t2** with the following structure:

`id` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL

Each table has about 50 data inside and my objective is to **create a view table** that combines both the data from the tables.

So far these are the queries I have tried that have shown some results to my objective:

```
Create view test_view as
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.code,
  t2.id,
  t2.code,

FROM test1 t1
CROSS JOIN test2 t2
```

Which returns the results but for some reason the values from the second table are duplicated by 50 times.

The other query I tried (which I had intended to put them all in the same column rather than making new column to differentiate t1 and t2) does the same

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM test1.t1 as a 
LEFT JOIN test2.t2 as b ON a.id <> b.id;
```

INNER JOIN , OUTER JOIN, CROSS JOIN show the same result of duplicated data.

I tried using **UNION** but the view table doesn't allow me to edit the columns when UNION is used.

I tried looking around on the internet for days on hours end but I can't seem to figure out the logic to do it. I would appreciate some assistance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Do the data link together somehow? Cross join means “take all rows of table A and link them with all rows of table B” so if both have 50 rows you get 50*50 results. The only way you’ll only get 50 rows is by joining them somehow, row to row

Comment: Well basically, they are both used for different front-ends but using the same back end (report generator). My objective is to create a view so that any UPDATE,INSERT OR ALTER statements can be done through the view table itself rather than switching between databases

Comment: You need to use UNION ALL for this. What do you mean "the view table does not allow me to *edit the columns*"?

Comment: If I use join, on phpmyadmin I'm able to edit the data within the rows from the view and the data is updated on the table. However when using UNION the individual rows lose their underlying table identity so the edit option isn't in the view anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of JOIN is to produce a virtual table containing all combinations of pairs of rows from the joined tables meeting the ON conditions. You have no ON condition, so you get all possible pairs of rows: a useless explosion of data.

If you want to concatenate the two tables so they appear as one, you should use UNION or maybe UNION ALL if you want duplicates preserved.

But it makes no sense to try to INSERT rows into a view defined as a UNION of two tables: the INSERTed row must go into one of the physical tables. When you try to INSERT it into the view, you provide no clue to your table server about which physical table to use.

You can use your view to retrieve data, even as you INSERT or UPDATE either test1.t1 or test2.t2.

Comment: I'm sorry it slipped my mind I didn't meant to say that it was for insert purposes, basically I wanted the view for was so that it will display all the data from all tables into a reportcontroller for the admin backend